# tournament winner python while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, while-loop, tournament

I made a function 'Match' which takes two country and return a winner according to my algorithm.
EX)

```
def Match(England, Brazil) ----> England, 
def Match(Mexico, France) ---> France
```

I need to write function Winner which takes list of 2^n nations and run a tournament and find a winner.
EX)

```
def Winner([England, Brazil, Mexico, France]) ---> France 

England---Brazil,        Mexico---France  (Semifinal)

England---France (final)

France (winner) Return value
```

The length of nation list differs and I cannot make a winner choosing algorithm. The match-up is It would be great if the code uses while loop rather than for loop ^^.

Comment: Can you share your code please ? [edit] your post and add it

Comment: what's exactly your question ?

Comment: I am having trouble in creating a function 'Winner' which chooses the winner of the tournament.

Comment: Can you share a small CSV example ? for me to understand the data

Comment: Is all your code mandatory regarding rules from the exercice or not ? Like for the `match` rules

Comment: there is A LOT of improvements to do to your code, you're doing same things SO many times instead of 1, come here and we'll work on it https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230994/67042729-tournament-winner

Comment: I cannot enter the room and chat

Comment: It says I need 20 more reputation ...??

Comment: all functions are mandatory and I'll post the cvs

Comment: Guinea,Conakry,9.5,-13.700000,GN,Africa//
Guinea-Bissau,Bissau,11.85,-15.583333,GW,Africa//
Guyana,Georgetown,6.8,-58.150000,GY,South America//
Haiti,Port-au-Prince,18.533333333333335,-72.333333,HT,North America//
...

Comment: @태주강 come in the chat now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230998/discussion-between-azro-and-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `tournament` method should make matches between consecutive pairs of players, for `["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]` it should be `a/b`, `c/d`, `e/f` and `g/h`

You can achieve these with slicing and `zip`

- `countries[::2]` takes 1 on 2 so `["a", "c", "e", "g"]`
- `countries[1::2]` same but starting at 1 so `["b", "d", "f", "h"]`
- `zip` pairs these 2 lists to create pairs of opponents

Keep the winner of each match, and call `tournament` recursivly with the next round of players which contains half of players

```
# FOR DEMO PURPOSER
def match(country_a, country_b):
    return random.choice([country_a, country_b])

def tournament(countries):
    n = len(countries)
    if not ((n & (n - 1) == 0) and n != 0):
        raise Exception("Size isn't power of 2")

    if n == 2:
        return match(*countries)

    next_round = []
    for player1, player2 in zip(countries[::2], countries[1::2]):
        winner = match(player1, player2)
        next_round.append(winner)

    return tournament(next_round)
```

Using `list-comprehension` the for-loop and `return` can be replaced with

```
return tournament([match(p1, p2) for p1, p2 in zip(countries[::2], countries[1::2])])
```

---

### Improvement full code

After some time and discussion with the OP here's a major improvement of the [full code](https://pastebin.com/LutfkgHW) with the major rules :

- don't call the exact same method in a loop, do it outside
- don't call a method again and again if it does the same, store the data somewhere

Comment: It worked and I finally understand the code.

Comment: However, I was working on a tutor program and popped a Time Limit Exceeded problem... HaHa...

Comment: @태주강 a time limit ? I can't see how to improve that, it does the minimum of matches possible, the only way to gain time is on `match` method, can you edit your initial post and add your `match` code ? You can think about voting up that answer, and accepting it (green tick on left) it if satisfies you ;)

Comment: I actually had many codes before the 'tournament' method....Whole code is over 100 length and just like you said, the previous code occurs the problem.

Comment: I will try my best to simplify my code to shorter the operation time

Comment: I don't know what you mean at the last sentence. You mean posting my code here?

Comment: @태주강 As I asked already 2 times : it would be nice to post YOUR `match` code INTO your initial post up there yes, you may click 'edit' on your question post and add it (see my comment under your post, it also contains the 'edit' link for YOUR post)

Comment: Got it. I was just little bit sorry(?) to post my long code and you to read it all...